# Python XPath selector not working with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried to automate some inputs. For this I need to input some text after the 
 tag.
To identify the place where to input I tried XPath for fowlloing HTML code.

```
<span data-offset-key="1dq3m-0-0">
  <br data-text="true">
</span>
```

Here is what I wrote in python.

```
buf_comp_text = 'foobar'
el_xp_comp_text = '//*[@data-text]'

...

## create post in queue (comment)
print('create post in queue - text')
post_txt = driver.find_element_by_xpath(el_xp_comp_text).send_keys(buf_comp_text)
```

Unfortunately I alwas get error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@data-text]"}
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML of the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of targetting the `<br>` tag you need to target the `<span>` tag you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  buf_comp_text = 'foobar'
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[data-offset-key]").send_keys(buf_comp_text)
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  buf_comp_text = 'foobar'
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-offset-key][.//br[@data-text]]").send_keys(buf_comp_text)
  ```

---

Ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  buf_comp_text = 'foobar'
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-offset-key]"))).send_keys(buf_comp_text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  buf_comp_text = 'foobar'
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-offset-key][.//br[@data-text]]"))).send_keys(buf_comp_text)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error.  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@data-offset-key][.//br[@data-text]]"}

Comment: @MarkusF Did you try with the _CssSelector_ / _WebDriverWait_?

Comment: Also the CSS version creates the error. selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span[data-offset-key]"}

Comment: @MarkusF how about implementing the _WebDriverWait_?

Comment: Tried it: Different error message.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MFE\python\py_social_bot\py_buffer_bot.py", line 55, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-offset-key][.//br[@data-text]]"))).send_keys(buf_comp_text)
  File "C:\Users\markusf\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:

Comment: Same for the CSS version.

Comment: found a solution. a simple wait solved it.Thank you @DebanjanB for the directions